# Stop Excel auto correcting one word

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't want to turn off the auto correct feature entirely in Excel, but I someone whose name is "Alway" and Excel INSISTS on changing it to Always which then breaks my lookups.

I've gone into Options>Proofing, but the exception rule only seems to apply to capitalisation, I've tried to add a "Replace With" which didn't work, and I can't find anywhere else to try?

Suggestions welcome. I'm using Office 365.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:
Open up the proofing options, in excel 2016 you would do the following, (i believe it is similar structure in 365)

File > options > proofing

then choose AutoCorrect Options...

under here you have the Replace: and With: fields, scroll down to where Alway is replaced with Always and delete that option. If it is not there it should not change it automatically. Once deleted click close.

EG: [image: example]